# Spring Prototype scope and implementation specific properties

Tags: spring, jdbc, configuration, jms, distributed-system

I am designing a distributed data warehouse that supports sharding and replication. Now let's suppose I have a manager application that maintains a "list" of all the database instances that belong to the data warehouse somewhere in a database table (in some "master" database) together with their type, e.g., Oracle, MySql, etc., and credentials, e.g., server name, user name, password, database name, etc. (note that this could also be a distributed configuration service like Zookeeper). Let's also suppose that given one row *x* from this table, I want to be able to create a native `DataSource` object for *x* at runtime, i.e., as the manager application needs it. What I need to do is reading the row for database *x* from the master database, get the type of the database, its credentials and create an instance of the `DataSource` implementation provided by the vendor (I don't want to use wrappers such as `DriverManagerDataSource` and the likes). I'd like to be able to add new JDBC drivers from configuration only, without recompiling.

Now here's my implementation idea. Given a list of *N* JDBC drivers, I could create *N* Spring prototype beans, one per `DataSource` and then when my application needs an instance for database *x*, create a new instance from one of the *N* prototypes and **then** set the right credentials for *x*.

This is the tricky part: I don't want to have to write code to do the above *for each different driver*. I'd like somehow to put placeholders in my Spring prototype and then fill them at runtime with a map from the database fields to the native `DataSource` setters for those. For example, I could have two prototypes such as:

```
<bean id="postgresDatasourcePrototype" scope="prototype"
    class="org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.SimpleDataSource">
    <property name="serverName" value="${db.host}"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="${db.name}"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="${db.port}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.pwd}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ingresDatasourcePrototype" scope="prototype"
    class="com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDataSource">
    <property name="serverName" value="${db.host}"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="${db.name}"/>
    <property name="portName" value="${db.port}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.pwd}"/>
</bean>
```

and I would want to bind the placeholders with parameters from the row for *x*.

Notice that although the properties for most JDBC drivers are similar, (1) there is no common interface and (2) there can be variation, e.g., portNumber vs portName above. If there's no out-of-the-box way to do so using Spring, the only thing I could think of is to provide a map from the fields of *x* to the properties of the JDBC datasource for each driver (at configuration time) and then use reflection to actually set those properties, which is basically what Spring does under the cover.

EDIT: Just to make it clear, there can be *N* different JDBC drivers, and I might need to create *M* distinct instances of the data source for that driver, each with different credentials read from a different row *x*.

Note that I want a general solution, i.e., it should work for JMS `ConnectionFactory`s as well.

Is there a way to do this using Spring? I was looking at PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer but it doesn't look like it fits my use case.

Thanks!

Giovanni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my 2 cents:
You can use an holder bean for every RDBMS config in this way and bind values with spEL:

```
class RDBMSConfigBean {
  String host;
  String name;
  String port;
  String user;
  String pwd;

  /* All accessors  */
}
class RDBMSConfigBeanHolder {
  RDBMSConfigBean pgConfig;
  RDBMSConfigBean ingresConfig;

  /* All accessors */
}
<bean id="rdbmsConfigHolder" class="RDBMSConfigBeanHolder" />
<bean id="ingresDatasourcePrototype" scope="prototype" class="com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDataSource">
  <property name="serverName" value="#{rdbmsConfigHolder.ingresConfig.host}"/>
  <!-- other props --> 
</bean>
```

In your application code you can `@Autowire` `rdbmsConfigHolder` and fill right properties from every database row.

Comment: Does this solve the problem of creating _N_ different instances of, say, ingresDatasourcePrototype each having different credentials?

Comment: Sorry, I think you want one different datasource for every type. I'll remove part about lazyinit. The first part of answer can be a solution, IMO. You need application code to fill holder data - of course - and every call to `ingresDatasourcePrototype` will get current (latest filled) credentials

Comment: Yeah I want _N_ different instances for every type. I still don't see how your solution helps with that, can you specify please? SpEL seems very promising. Thanks!

Comment: Oh so you're saying I would have one instance of RDBMSConfigBean per type of datasource and _before_ I create a new datasource I have to change its properties? This means if tomorrow I want to add a new JDBC driver I still have to change RDBMSConfigBeanHolder and recompile?

Comment: You can have N instance, but you have only ONE bean definition in you context.XML so you can wire only one set of credentials for every datasource (else you need N bean definition in your XML). I can't see other ways

Comment: Yes. else you can use a map in behalf of RDBMSConfigBean and a map of map for the holder (<RDBMSType as String, Map<String,String>) then use spEL to wire data. But you need to re-deploy if you have a new driver (you need bean config in your XML)

Comment: This works by adding to RDBMSConfigBean a method that takes my object representing my database row and creates a DataSource. The method has to be synchronized. It first sets the properties from the database row and then creates the DataSource bean from the prototype. The name of the prototype is specified in a map (jdbc driver -> prototype bean name).